# Tank barrel rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello i'm making a game in unity about tanks and currently i'm making a script about the turret of a tank and I've come to a problem with the tank gun.
When i'm rotating the tower the gun still stays in the same position facing the same way all the time

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TankManager: MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject turret;
    public GameObject gun;
    float mouseX=0;
    float mouseY=-90;
    public float moveSpeed;
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MoveTower();
    }
    void MoveTower()
    {
        mouseX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        mouseY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")*-1;
        turret.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(turret.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector4(-90, mouseX, -180)), moveSpeed);
        gun.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(gun.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(mouseY, 0, turret.transform.rotation.z)), moveSpeed);

    }
}
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: is gun child of turret?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hum if i guess the problem without any other precision, you should test the localRotation for the gun

```
gun.transform.localrotation = .....
```

rotation is in worldspace, localrotation is for rotation gun relative the turret

Comment: just a question have you a good 3d object tank i am looking for?

Comment: well what exact type of tank do you want. I have a pretty good Tiger I model but without interior

Comment: how can i send it to you?

Comment: sent it, check if you have it